# Android scroll to the bottom of a listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

this is not a repeat of another question.. it's more an expansion. I hope :)

I've a list view with a few hundred items in it.. They are date stamped entries in another view.

When I show the screen I want it to scroll to the bottom, so the most recent items are displayed, but in a logical "end of the thing" sort of way.

```
m_list.setSelection(m_list.getCount()-1);
```

Kewl as... but :( Now my list won't scroll.  It seem stuck on the bottom.  I can see the "truck" and it's tiny and at the bottom.

Ok.. so my questy is thus.. How do I start off by scrolling to the bottom, but still allow the user (me) to scroll up when they (me again) want to scroll up.

Comment: Where do you call the setSelection function?

Comment: OMG!  That question was bril' I was calling it inside my ondraw.. It was initially part of my testing code... AWESOME!

Comment: Upvote for a bril' answer?

Comment: @MollyCat User could I have the correct answer, If you have solved this issue?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

set the following on your `listview` in the XML.

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Comment: It didn't actually.  I already had m_list.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL); in my code.  My list seems locked.

Comment: m_list.setStackFromBottom(true);  didn't seem to do anything either.  Note.. i have not defined my ctrl in XML

Comment: I accepted the answer because once I realized a bug i had, this and my code made everything work perfectly

Answer (score 12):

You can use following code to reach at bottom of list view.

```
listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(listView.getCount());
        }
    }, 500);
```

This will set delay of 500 ms. Or you can use

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(listView.getCount());
        }
    });
```

This will scroll your list view pragmatically.

Comment: This wont scroll to bottom. This will, as method name suggests set your selection at TOP of last item. If your item is pretty long (say, long header) this will do nothing useful.

Comment: listView.setSelection(listView.getCount()); 
should be
listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);