# How to scroll ListView to the bottom?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

I though this would be a simple task, but apparently there is no way to scroll listview to the bottom. All solutions that I found are using variations of `setSelection(lastItem)` method which only sets selection to last item, but does not scrolls to the bottom of it.

In my case I have a empty listview (with a long <s>empty view</s> header set) and I want to scroll to bottom of it.

So, is there a way to do it?

Edit:

So for those who are interested the working solution is:

```
getListView().setSelectionFromTop(0, -mHeader.getHeight());
```

and

```
getListView().scrollTo(mOffset)
```

This also works, with right offset (calculated based on current scroll position), but might give you some unexpected results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android scroll to the bottom of a listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454953/android-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-listview)

Comment: refer this best solution if you are developing an chatting app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using `list.scrollTo(0, list.getHeight());`

Comment: This method causes overscroll - listview is extended (with lot's of empty space at bottom) and the moment you try to scroll it it shrinks back.

Comment: Ok, the direction was right you just need to scroll with a right offset.

Answer (score 38):

If you want the list view to be scrolled always at the bottom even when you are updating the list view dynamically then you can add these attributes in list view itself.

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Answer (score 19):

use the following

```
    lv.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Comment: Please read my question again, there is only one child in the listivew and I want to scroll to the bottom of it. There is no adapter, only empty view (view set through lv.setEmptyView(view)).

Comment: Sorry, not empty view, but header.

Comment: sorry mate no idea for header

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to have a scroll animation programmatically you could easily scroll to the bottom of the list using:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());
```

scrolling to the top most of the list can be achieved using:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.. it will solve your problem, i tried it and it works great.

```
   listView.post(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
             listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

### Its working for me

Answer (score 1):

Use following and try.

listview.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1);

Comment: Please read my question again, there is only one child in the listivew and I want to scroll to the bottom of it. There is no adapter, only empty view (view set through lv.setEmptyView(view)).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListView.getCount() - 1)`. This way, you're not forced into selecting the last row. Plus, you get some smooth, beautiful scrolling! (:

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem, This works best for me

```
listView.setSelection(listView.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no adapter set to your ListView then it has no children at all, empty view is not a child of your ListView

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got it a little bit wrong here, there is situation where there are only empty view (no problems here), and when there are only header, which counts as children (need to scroll to it's bottom).