# scrolle to a table raw in a scrolle view at run time

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

In my Android project I'm using a **table layout** contained in a **scroll view**. When a product is selected from a spinner the **table view** must automatically **scroll** to the **table raw** showing the relevant product's details. Unfortunately I can't post any of my code work. I have a big problem in scrolling the view. So can someone help me with some helpful code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one solution is to know the index in your list of the selected product. Then you'll have to measure the childs in your ScrollView. When you know the sizes of your children and the index of the child you want to scroll to you can use ScrollView.scrollTo(x, y)
the y will be something like this: index * heightOfChild.

This is ofc if your childs are of the same size. Otherwise youll have to measure each child separatly.

Edit:

scrollTo apparently "clamps the scrolling to the bounds of our child." Not sure what it means... But you could try scrollBy(x, y) the documentation doesnt write anything about clamps for that.

if you are using a listView you could try setSelection() as described here:
[Android scroll to the bottom of a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454953/android-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-listview)

Comment: OK. its working. Thanks. But after it scroll to the table raw I can't scroll any more.I have had to reload the view (There is an option to reload). I look for some thing "enable scroll", but I couldn't find one. I would appreciate your help in this matter.